# Save info Firebase logged user for switch user no need reauthenticate?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

My app allow user login by phone. User can login by phone number A, and then login to phone number B, and C , D ...

How could i do to save "Something" to allow user sometime, if they want, they just choose phone number A, B, C .... to switch account and no need to verify by sms code again ?

Im using Flutter and my app is published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Tokens.

When you authenticate the first time, create a file (a token) and encrypt their password and phone id, and name the file with their username.

When they authenticate, before the sms message is sent check for the token, decrypt it and see if the password works.

Comment: When user login by phone, they just receive sms code for verify so there is no password. With sms code + verifycationId , app use to login user . And then, Firebase return FirebaseUser.
So, may i miss something ?